# How to extend the list data structure in Python without violating Liskov substitution - supply an attribute instead of an instance?

Tags: python, list, inheritance, liskov-substitution-principle

I’m building a class that extends the `list` data structure in Python, called a Partitional. I’m adding a few methods that I find myself using frequently when dividing a list into partitions.

The class is initialized with a (nullable) list, which exists as an attribute on the class.

```py
class Partitional(list):
    """Extends the list data type. Adds methods for dividing a list into partition sets 
    and returning data about those partition sets"""

    def __init__(self, source_list: list=[]):
        super().__init__()
        self.source_list: list = source_list
        self.n: int = len(source_list)

        ...
```

I want to be able to reliably replace `list` instances with `Partitional` instances without violating Liskov substitution. So for `list`’s methods, I wrote methods on the `Partitional` class that operate on self.source_list, e.g.

```py
    ...

    def remove(self, matched_item):
        self.source_list.remove(matched_item)
        self.__init__(self.source_list)
        
    def pop(self, *args):
        popped_item = self.source_list.pop(*args)
        self.__init__(self.source_list)
        return popped_item
        
    def clear(self):
        self.source_list.clear()
        self.__init__(self.source_list)

    ...
```

(the `__init__` call is there because the `Partitional` class builds some internal attributes based on `self.source_list` when it’s initialized, so these need to be rebuilt if `source_list` changes.)

And I also want Python’s built-in methods that take a `list` as an argument to work with a `Partitional` instance, so I set to work writing method overrides for those as well, e.g.

```py
    ...
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.source_list)
        
    def __enumerate__(self):
        return enumerate(self.source_list)
    ...
```

The relevant built-in methods are a finite set for any given Python version, but... is there not a simpler way to do this?

**My question:**

**Is there a way to write a class such that, if an instance of that class is used as the argument for a function, the class provides an *attribute* to the function instead, by default?**

That way I’d only need to override this default behaviour for a subset of built-in methods.

So for example, if a use case involving a `list` instance looks like this:

```py
example_list: list = [1,2,3,4,5]
length = len(example_list)
```

we substitute a `Partitional` instance built from the same list:

```py
example_list: list = [1,2,3,4,5]
example_partitional = Partitional(example_list)
length = len(example_partitional)
```

and what’s “actually” happening is this:

```py
length = len(example_partitional.source_list)
i.e. 
length = len([1,2,3,4,5])
```

**Other notes:**

In working on this, I’ve realized that there are two broad categories of Liskov substitution violation possible:

1. Inherent violation, where the structure of the child class will make it incompatible with *any* use case where the child class is used in place of the parent class, e.g. if you override some fundamental property or structure of the parent.
2. Context-dependent violation, where, for any given piece of software, so long as you never use the child class in a way that would violate Liskov substitution, you’re fine. E.g. You override a method on the parent class that would change how a built-in function acts when it takes an instance of the class as an argument, but you *never use that built-in method with the class instance* in your system. Or any system that depends on your system. Or... (you see how relying on this caveat is not foolproof)

What I’m looking to do is come up with a technique that will protect against both categories of violation, without having to worry about use cases and context.

Comment: As an aside, calling `self.__init__(self.source_list)` like that is confusing. Just put that logic in some other method, call *that* method in `__init__` and wherever else you need it.

Comment: `__enumerate__` is not a magic method... what do you expect that to do? work with `enumerate`? That isn't how Python works.

Comment: Anyway, honestly, I see *no* good reason for inherting from `list` here. You are pretty much overriding all the relevant methods... Look into [`collections.UserList`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList) generally, inheriting from built-in types is inadvisable, unfortunately.